# how to select NaN rows and assign value_A to a new column? code df.loc['condition_1' & 'condition_2' & 'df.column_a == ''] = 'value_a'

Tags: python, pandas, nan, pandas-loc

I have the data similar as below:

```
   A    B    C
0  M    M    M
1  Y    M    M
2  Y  NaN  NaN
3  Y    Y  etc
```

what i need is:

```
   A    B    C  F
0  M    M    M  3
1  Y    M    M  4
2  Y  NaN  NaN  0
3  Y    Y  etc  5
```

I don't know how to deal with rows[2, 3], here I list the code I used but not work below:

```py
df.loc[df['A'] == 'M', 'F'] = '3'
df.loc[((df.A != 'M') & (df.B == 'M')), 'F'] = '4'
df.loc[(df.A != 'M') & (df.B != 'M') & (df.C != ''), 'F'] = '5'
df.loc[(df.A != 'M') & (df.B != 'M') & (df.C == ''), 'F'] = '0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
m1 = df['A'] == 'M'
m2 = df['B'] == 'M'
m3 = df['C'].notna()

df['F'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['3','4','5'], default='0')
print (df)
   A    B    C  F
0  M    M    M  3
1  Y    M    M  4
2  Y  NaN  NaN  0
3  Y    Y  etc  5
```

If necessary add more conditions use `~` for invert mask and chain by `bitwise AND` - `&`:

```
m1 = df['A'] == 'M'
m2 = df['B'] == 'M'
m3 = df['C'].notna()
m11 = ~m1
m22 = ~m2
m33 = ~m3

df['F'] = np.select([m1, m2 & m11, m3 & m11 & m22], ['3','4','5'], default='0')
```

EDIT:

Your solution is possible change by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and 
[`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 'M', 'F'] = '3'
df.loc[((df.A != 'M') & (df.B == 'M')), 'F'] = '4'
df.loc[(df.A != 'M') & (df.B != 'M') & (df.C.notna()), 'F'] = '5' 
df.loc[(df.A != 'M') & (df.B != 'M') & (df.C.isna()), 'F'] = '0'
```

Comment: thans a lot! BTW, what a pity `.loc[]` seems can not work.

Comment: @Sean.H - In your solution use `df.loc[(df.A != 'M') & (df.B != 'M') & (df.C.notna()), 'F'] = '5'
df.loc[(df.A != 'M') & (df.B != 'M') & (df.C.isna()), 'F'] = '0'`

Comment: Thumb up! Could you also give me a hent which one is better, or in other word the differences?

Comment: and FYI, if you can updating them into the answer, I think the others (who's looking for an answer like me) will appreciate it very much :-)

Comment: @Sean.H - Main difference is `np.select`  is numpy solution and `loc` is pandas solution. Obviously performance in numpy is better.

Comment: @Sean.H - `df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)` for 4k rows - `In [7]: %%timeit
   ...: df.loc[df['A'] == 'M', 'F'] = '3'
   ...: df.loc[((df.A != 'M') & (df.B == 'M')), 'F'] = '4'
   ...: df.loc[(df.A != 'M') & (df.B != 'M') & (df.C.notna()), 'F'] = '5' 
   ...: df.loc[(df.A != 'M') & (df.B != 'M') & (df.C.isna()), 'F'] = '0'
   ...: 
15.3 ms ± 2.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: `In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: m1 = df['A'] == 'M'
   ...: m2 = df['B'] == 'M'
   ...: m3 = df['C'].notna()
   ...: m11 = ~m1
   ...: m22 = ~m2
   ...: m33 = ~m3
   ...: 
   ...: df['F'] = np.select([m1, m2 & m11, m3 & m11 & m22], ['3','4','5'], default='0')
   ...: 
2.79 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Comment: Great! Thanks a loooot!